# Personal Campaign Pages (pcp) related to a campaign

Tags: contribution-page, pcp, personal-campaign-pages, civicampaign

We're trying to create a peer-peer funding application so people can support an individual "Cause".  CiviCrm allows a PCP to associate with a contribution page (or event) but I think associating with a Campaign makes more sense.

Currently, do we need a separate contribution page for each Cause we want to fund?  All the donation pages are the same with just the title, dates, status and goal changing.  If we have 100 causes this means we have to maintain 100 pages and update them all if we want to change something.  Also, I can't see in the API how to setup/configure the PCP/Widget so that would need to be done manually or via extension.

Has anyone tried to associate the PCP with a "Campaign" so it is not necessary to create a separate contribution page for each entity we want to fund?

Campaigns seem to be a better fit for PCP - you could simply create a contribution (without a contribution page) and associate it with a Campaign.

Ideally you could pass a campaign id to a contribution page and manage a "generic" donation page that would dynamically associate with a campaign.

I understand that Webforms can do this some of this but there is a lot of great, built-in logic (tell-a-friend, create PCP, etc.) that is in the donation pipeline so it seems unfortunate to have to recreate it.