# Widgets for Campaigns (as opposed to Contribution Pages)

Tags: contribution-page, civicampaign, widget

I know about the widgets that can be generated for Contribution Pages -- is there a similar function for Campaigns? For example, donations that came in through one or more different contribution pages could be designated as the same campaign, offline donations, etc.

Comment: duplicate post: http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/4894/personal-campaign-pages-pcp-related-to-a-campaign

Comment: Agreed. Was going to close as duplicate but it won't let me since neither has an accepted answer.